# How to perform lasso regression with a single predictor column?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'd like to build a lasso regression model in R, and the go-to package seems to be glmnet. However, glmnet doesn't seem to allow for a single predictor as shown below. This works:

```
x <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
y <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=1)
lasso <- glmnet(x, y, family = "gaussian")
```

But this does not:

```
x <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=1)
y <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=1)
lasso <- glmnet(x, y, family = "gaussian")
Error: x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns
```

How can I build a lasso regression model with a single predictor? Thanks!

Comment: Add a column of 1s?

Comment: Why do you want to do lasso with a single variable anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The code will be

lasso <- glmnet(cbind(0,x), y, family = "gaussian")