# How to use gamma glm (with the fixed shape parameter) in R?

Tags: r

The reference is this website: https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnetFamily.html

It says

> glmnet can fit penalized GLMs for any family as long as the family can
> be expressed as a family object. In fact, users can make their own
> families, or customize existing families, just as they can for regular
> GLMs.

Now I need to create my own family. It's gamma family with the shape parameter is fixed at 1. And the link function is standard log function.

I try this code first:

```
cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(all_datasets[,c("V1","V2")]), y=all_datasets$V4, family= Gamma(link="log"), 
    type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100)
```

The above code works. But I am not sure whether its shape parameter is fixed at 1. The tutorial on the website lack the clear relevant information.

But the above code also has a problem. If I only use 1 variable as my x, then it doesn't work.

```
cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(all_datasets[,c("V1")]), y=all_datasets$V4, family= Gamma(link="log"), 
       type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100)

Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,  : 
  x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use the LASSO with one predictor. That doesn't make any sense. Also, why do you believe your code fixes the shape parameter at 1? A gamma distribution with `shape = 1` is just the exponential distribution.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for pointing out that. I currently do a small problem on gamma glm. To make it simpler, I assume the shape = 1, then  it is reduced to 1 parameter problem. I don't know in the glmnet function, what the distribution and parameters they used under family= Gamma(link="log").

Comment: @Roland Also to answer your question "use the LASSO with one predictor". It is iterative step. So first 1 predictor, then 2 predictors, then etc.

Comment: That's not how you use the LASSO. You should use all predictors and let the regularization and cross-validation do their job. Maybe read the second section of these lecture notes regarding Gamma GLMs: https://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Regression-GLM/Gamma/GammaGLM-01.pdf

Comment: The second problem is solved.  "use the LASSO with one predictor"The solution is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698836/how-to-perform-lasso-regression-with-a-single-predictor-column

Comment: @Roland I reorganize my question. And please see my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481572/in-glmnet-package-in-r-what-is-the-distribution-behind-family-gammalink-log