# In glmnet package in R, what is the distribution behind family= Gamma(link="log")?

Tags: r

In glmnet package in R, what is the distribution behind family= Gamma(link="log")?

Gamma distribution has 2 parameters, then I didn't find relevant information to know what the specific distribution format that family= Gamma(link="log") uses? I guess it could be gamma (1, scale parameter), then in this case, it is exponential distribution. But I am not sure.

Comment: See details here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnetFamily.pdf

Comment: @PGSA I already saw this. It's not clear since gamma has 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the parameters of a Gamma distribution if you want to draw from that distribution. However, fitting a model with glmnet will not estimate those parameters for you.

If you simply want to estimate the parameters of the Gamma distribution your dependent variable comes from, you can use the `fitdistrplus::fitdist` function.

Here is an example:

```r
> set.seed(1234)
> fitdistrplus::fitdist(rgamma(100, .4, 2), "gamma")

Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
       estimate Std. Error
shape 0.3961962 0.04528737
rate  2.0738449 0.40588978
```

As you can see the estimated parameters of the gamma distribution are quite close to the ones specified in the simulation (`rgamma` function).

You can replace the simulated gamma distribution by your own data and then of course you won't need the seed anymore.

Comment: Emm. I think coef(fit) returns the parameters.

Comment: AFAIK coef returns the coefficients of the retained predictors but not the parameters of the Gamma distribution.

Comment: However, if you want you can estimate those parameters with `MASS::gamma.shape` after fitting the model as glm.

Comment: yes, I know what you mean. You are correct. We are on the same page.

Comment: I want to know in glmnet package, when I specify  family= Gamma(link="log"), what do I really specify? Basically, I know Y|X is gamma distribution. Then what are the parameters? I guess it specifies shape parameter = 1. But I am not sure.

Comment: so my question can be reduced to where I can find coding information on  family= Gamma(link="log") in glmnet package?

Comment: @Jackie The shape parameter most certainly is not 1. Please read the Wikipedia article I have linked in a comment under your other question. Why are you interested in the parameters of the Gamma distribution? They are conditional on the values of the predictors.

Comment: @Jackie I have updated my answer with more information on estimating the parameters of a Gamma distribution from data.

Comment: Then please note that the link function does not affect the parameters of the distribution of the response (i.e., specifying link=log does not equate to specifying a shape of 1 for a Gamma distribution). I can only support @Roland's comments, it is not clear what you need. On one hand you are talking about lasso regression, on the other about estimating distribution parameters... If you want to ensure that you have selected an adequate distribution for your data, what you need to do is investigate the residuals.

Comment: But suppose I use fit = glmfit(x,y, family=gamma(link="log")). Then I use coef(fit). What are the coef(fit)?

Comment: @Jackie The coefficients of the [linear predictor part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Model_components) of the generalized linear model. You really need to inform yourself about generalized linear models.